# how to make it so that the code in the if statement is executed but only once until user enters another valid URL?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wanted to know how I could make my code so that once the user enters a  valid URL, it executes the code in the if statement only once until the user enters another valid URL and does not constantly execute the code. Thanks in advance.

**Code:**

```
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube



root = Tk()


frame1 = LabelFrame(root, padx = 50 , pady = 20 , borderwidth = 0 , highlightthickness = 0)

frame1.pack()


urlentryvar = StringVar()
urlentry = Entry(frame1, width =40, textvariable = urlentryvar, justify="center" , font =("Bauhaus 93" , 10))
urlentry.insert(0,"ENTER URL")
urlentry.grid(row=0,column=0 , columnspan =3, ipady = 10)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root,padx = 10, borderwidth = 0 , highlightthickness = 0)
frame2.pack(anchor=W)


TitleLabel = Label(frame2 , text=f"Title:", font =("Bauhaus 93" ,10))

TitleLabel.grid(row=0,column= 1,stick = NW )




def get_the_url_and_display_title():
    global url
    url = urlentry.get()
    
    
  
    
    if url[0:5] == "https":
        
             
        yt = YouTube(url)
        Youtube_video_title = yt.title
              
        TitleLabel.config(text=f"Title:{Youtube_video_title}")
            
    root.after(2000,get_the_url_and_display_title)    
get_the_url_and_display_title()
            
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your if statement will be executed at max once per function call.
I'm not sure if this is intentional, but both `urlget()` and `root.mainloop()` are inside `gettheurlanddisplaytitle()`. Maybe this is causing your problem?
(Oh, and one thing, try naming your functions something like `get_the_url_and_display_title()` in order to improve readability. I'll leave you with a link if you'd like to learn about [naming conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)).

Comment: sorry about that and no it was not intentional I made the edit.

Comment: No problem man, did it fix your problem?

Comment: well no, it didn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `root.after` that is quite unnecessary for what you are trying to achieve. You don't need to check if the URL is valid using the if-else block, `pytube` will raise an exception if an invalid URL is entered. Use try-except block to handle the exception.

Also, bind Return key to `get_the_url_and_display_title`. This way the function is executed only if the user presses the enter.  You could also create submit button instead.

Corrected code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube


def get_the_url_and_display_title(event):

    url = urlentry.get()
    text = "Error"
    
    try:    
        yt = YouTube(url)
        Youtube_video_title = yt.title
                  
        text=f"Title:{Youtube_video_title}"

    except Exception:
        pass

    TitleLabel.config(text=text)
    # root.after(2000, lambda :TitleLabel.config(text="Title:"))
    
    
root = Tk()


frame1 = LabelFrame(root, padx = 50 , pady = 20 , borderwidth = 0 , highlightthickness = 0)

frame1.pack()


urlentryvar = StringVar()
urlentry = Entry(frame1, width =40, textvariable = urlentryvar, justify="center" , font =("Bauhaus 93" , 10))
urlentry.insert(0,"ENTER URL")
urlentry.grid(row=0,column=0 , columnspan =3, ipady = 10)
urlentry.bind("<Return>", get_the_url_and_display_title)

frame2 = LabelFrame(root,padx = 10, borderwidth = 0 , highlightthickness = 0)
frame2.pack(anchor=W)


TitleLabel = Label(frame2 , text=f"Title:", font =("Bauhaus 93" ,10))

TitleLabel.grid(row=0,column= 1,stick = NW )

root.mainloop()
```

<sub>Also, note its better to use threading for IO-bound tasks</sub>